# Sending image file and xml with cURL

Tags: php, xml, curl

I have the following code which works just fine sending the $xml. However when i try to add a file to be sent with the xml as well i get an error. I tried using a postData array but then got an array to string error. The way i have it now works but it only sends the xml not the file. Any ideas on how I can send the @file with the postfields? Any help is appreciated

```
$header = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');
$xml['xml'] = '<UploadPhoto>';
$xml['xml'] .= '<ID>12345</ID>';
$xml['xml'] .= '<PhotoID>myphoto</PhotoID>';
$xml['xml'] .= '<Filename>myphoto.jpg</Filename>';
$xml['xml'] .= '<Instructions>Need cheeks less rosy</Instructions>';
$xml['xml'] .= '</UploadPhoto>';

$postData = array(
 'file' => '@/myphoto.jpg',
 'xml'  => $xml
);

$connection = curl_init();
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.myurl.com/api");
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
set_time_limit(108000);

$output = curl_exec($connection);
curl_close($connection);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#110442

Comment: This shows posting form fields, but I already have a xml string representation. When I combine them with the file using the @ it fails as an array to string conversion. How do i ensure the xml string I created stays an array?

Comment: The part I posted was talking about files, not only form field.

Comment: Yes, I see that and already have that in my code above. That was not my full question. im needing help with the combination of xml string and file as array properly.

Comment: You have an extra } after your $postData, can it help a little bit your problem?

Comment: no sorry, thats the closing if statement I did not include, i edited that out for clarity

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postData));
```

Comment: That does not seem to work as the API is not seeing the XML properly. However, its at least responding. im not getting the array to string error

Comment: You are currently sending only a string, not the content of the file in your $postData.                                                                      $postData = array(
  'file' => file_get_contents('myphoto.jpg'),
  'xml'  => $xml
 );

Comment: well getting closer, but the XML is not being seen by the API on the other side. So something is still amiss.

Comment: What's the code on the api side? What the api 'see' currently?

Comment: Unfortunately they have poor responses with their code. I just get No request found which is what i get when the xml sent is improper or not correctly sent. Using my $xml in postfields returns a proper response. using the array with the build query seems to add or change the data sent

Comment: Did you remove the http_build_query?

Comment: Also I suspect the header to be wrong but as we don't know what the API is expecting, it's not easy to solve the issue...